# Java, TDD True when not equals?

Tags: java, tdd

for some reason while testing this method during a lesson in class we found an issue we couldn't understand. When writing `System.out.println();` for some reason it passes?. Can someone explain why this is happening?

```
public class Zones {

public ZoneId getZoneId(String input) {

    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Stockholm")) {
        return ZoneId.of("Europe/Stockholm");
    }
    else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Shanghai")) {
        return ZoneId.of("Asia/Shanghai");
    } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Toronto")) {
        return ZoneId.of("America/Toronto");
    }
    else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Hamburg")) {
        return ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin");
    }
    else return null;
}

public LocalDateTime getZoneTime(ZoneId zoneId) {
    LocalDateTime lt = LocalDateTime.now(zoneId);
    return lt;
}
```

}

`private Zones z = new Zones();`

```
@Test
public void getZoneTimeTest () {
    System.out.println(z.getZoneTime(zIDToronto).getNano() );
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now(zIDToronto).getNano() );
    assertTrue(z.getZoneTime(zIDToronto).getNano() == LocalDateTime.now(zIDToronto).getNano());
}
```

Comment: Where is 'z' defined, and how does it fail?

Comment: you compare two different timestamps and are wondering why they're different? is that it?

Comment: `LocalDateTime.now(...).getNano()` is likely to produce a different time than what `z` refers to, especially since printing to the console can slow down execution measurably.

Comment: Beyond that: dont use assertTrue() like that. Rather use assertEquals, or even better: assertThat(), together with hamcrest matchers. But yes, to really help: provide a [mcve]

Comment: Question is why does it pass when using `System.out.println();` but fails when removing it? It should always fail? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Well, it's not tied to `System.out.println()`. When I simply print unrelated strings, it doesn't pass. When I get the printed values before the assert, without printing them, it passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally had some time to investigate this deeper.

I started experimenting and found after a while, that is in fact not the presence of `System.out.println` that influenced the result, but the fact that you instantiate 2 `LocalDateTime` instances before it.

Digging deeper, into the code of `LocalDateTime`, and the `SystemClock` (to which it delegates), I found that the sub milli precision was achieved by a call to the native call `jdk.internal.misc.VM#getNanoTimeAdjustment`.

That last call is OS specific. I experimented a bit with it and found that it doesn't return values linearly, as it gets called in a loop (assuming my loop ran fairly regularly).

So I decided to run some code to map the returned nano values.

I made this sampling code :

```
Clock clock = Clock.systemDefaultZone();

int samples = 1_000;
LocalDateTime[] instants = new LocalDateTime[samples];

int k = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < samples; i++) {
    instants[i] = LocalDateTime.now(clock);
    for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
        k = j % 2;
    }
}
```

wrote the values to a file, and then mapped the nano differences vs the first value into a graph :

[image: nano progression vs first invocation]

As you can see this graph (of 1000 values) makes intermittent leaps. This is obviously in part due to precision restriction of the underlying system. But wat struck me is that the first two values consistently were different. It's as if upon regular access the OS system starts caching the value for a while (possibly to avoid strain on the system resources).

But the result it seems is that you set yourself up for getting the same value on the 3rd and 4th call (unless enough time has passed).

That would explain why your test passes with, and fails without those prior instantiations.

As an aside, for unit tests you don't want to rely on a system clock. Make sure your business code gets it's time from an injected Clock instance. Then you can inject a custom clock for tests, and test whether your code will run on a DST changeover date or on a leap day without having to wait several months.

Answer (score 0):

The test involves [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) and passes (sometimes) because of the timing and adding statements changes the timing and therefore test outcome.

The condition that is checked in the assertion basically is the equality of the nanoseconds parts of two date-times taken one after another in succession.

Given that by default `System.currentTimeMillis()` is used internally by `LocalDateTime.now` and it has at most millisecond precision the check will succeed if the second sequence of invocations to get the number of nanoseconds is quick enough (that is the actual sequence of calls leading to invocation of `System.currentTimeMillis` finished within the same millisecond as the first).

When you invoke the functions used to obtain the value of nanosecond before the actual assertion the corresponding classes are loaded, the code of corresponding methods get into the CPU caches etc. This makes the second pair of calls to get the number of nanoseconds run much quicker.